# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I am using python 3.4.3 on mac. I installed it with homebrew, so I am not sure if its just my code or if I need to reinstall.

here is the error I get:

```
File "~/Documents/python game/main/main.py", line 16, in ?
if Event.type == pygame.QUIT():
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Here is my Code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode ((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption('game')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

while running:

for Event in pygame.event.get():
    if Event.type == pygame.QUIT():
        running = False
    print(Event)

pygame.display.update()

clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: In your for loop, change it to `pygame.quit()`. `QUIT` seems to be an integer constant used by PyGame.

Comment: @Ken no, that should be `Event.type == pygame.QUIT`; no parentheses. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10080715/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Indeed it should. I read the `pygame.quit()` at the bottom and somehow thought that should be called in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that you called pygame.QUIT. Or, pygame.QUIT is a number. So you get an error.
you must do it like this:

```
...
if Event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    ...
```